# using google app engine with JPA and cloud sql not returning any records using endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql

I have an Android project and an app engine connected project. I am using the following:
JPA v2,
App Engine 1.7.6,
Java 1.7 compiler,
Eclipse 4.2 Juno,
EclipseLink 2.4.x

I am using Cloud sql db. I am able to connect successfully in the JPA and DB Persective window and query data back ok. I have set up my app engine to have the SQL Development to be connected to my CLOUD Sql db.

I have one table defined as follows:

```
CREATE Table Test(codeid varchar(3) NOT NULL,codedesc varchar(20) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (codeid));
```

The Entity class is as follows:

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.*;



    @Entity
    public class Test implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String codeid;

    private String codedesc;

    public Test() {
    }

    public String getCodeid() {
    return this.codeid;
    }

    public void setCodeid(String codeid) {
this.codeid = codeid;
    }

    public String getCodedesc() {
        return this.codedesc;
    }

    public void setCodedesc(String codedesc) {
        this.codedesc = codedesc;
    }
    }
```

the endpoint class is as follows:

```
 @Api(name = "testendpoint" , version = "v1")
    public class TestEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @ApiMethod(    httpMethod = "GET",    name = "listtest.list",     path = "ch/list")
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    public CollectionResponse<Test> listTest(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<Test> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select x from Test x");
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<Test>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (Test obj : execute);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            mgr.close();
        }

            return CollectionResponse.<Test> builder().setItems(execute).setNextPageToken       (cursorString).build();
    }

    private boolean containsCodeheader(Test test) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try {
            Test item = mgr
                    .find(Test.class, test.getCodeid());
            if (item == null) {
                contains = false;
            }
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }

        private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    }

    }
```

persistence.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider></provider>
        <class>com.testApp.Test</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
```

What I am trying to do is run my endpoint to get a list of records back . I When I run the following I dont get any errors in the console.

localhost:8888/_ah/api/testendpoint/v1/ch/list

I get the follwoing in the Google Chrome when I know there are records in my table.

```
 {
    "items" : [ ]
  }
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

I have carried out further testing and found my above example works for another test app engine project I created before from scratch. A difference I have found is, when I run the broken app engine locally I get the following warning in the Console window which I dont in the working test app:

The backing store, \war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created.

Comment: you say you're using EclipseLink, yet put various DataNucleus properties in there (that are inapplicable for "cloud SQL". Suggest you decide what JPA implementation to use and set properties accordingly.

Comment: Thank you DataNucleus for your reply. I have deleted the EclipseLink tag on this question. My persistence.xml file is a result of following the google setup instructions and does include the cloud sql connection details etc.

Comment: Why delete "eclipselink" tag if you're using EclipseLink as JPA provider? If persistence.xml includes the EclipseLink connection details then why not post the real one, rather than the one from GAE/Datastore usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am happy to report that I found the answer to this issue. Turns out I was doing everything correctly. The only thing I had to do was take the following line out of persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
```

I already had the following set in the file:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://Your db connection/databasename"/>.
```